# Асинхронная запись в сокет. MSVC. Exception: "cannot dereference string iterator..."

Tags: c++, visual-c++, исключения, gcc, boost

Для сетевой части используется boost asio. На Windows(MSVC) выскакивает exception: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]"

Кусок кода:

```
void Send()
    {
        std::stringstream buffer;



async_write(*this->socket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(buffer.str()),
                        boost::bind(&Socket::HandleWrite,
                                    this,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));   
        }
```

Поверхностно я понимаю, что локальная переменная buffer уничтожается и это каким-то образом приводит к exception. Но при этом данные посылаются, потери не наблюдаю, хотя не уверен. Самое интересное, что на Linux(gcc) такого exception нету. 
Можете подробнее объяснить почему так происходит?

Comment: `boost::asio::buffer` ссылается на переданный буфер, а вы передаете временный объект - строку, которая сразу же выходит из области видимости. Передаваемый объект должен оставаться валидным до успешного завершения записи или до возникновения ошибки.

Comment: Даже не "локальная переменная buffer уничтожается", а временный `std::string` объект `buffer.str()` уничтожается сразу же по завершению вызова `async_write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, в общем-то вы верно понимаете, что проблема связана с тем, что строка приказывает долго жить до того, как выполняется запись ее содержимого.

Сообщение вы получаете потому, что работаете в отладочном режиме (если перейдете к релизу, этого сообщения не будет... но сама ошибка не исчезнет).

Данные посылаются потому, что это UB, и возможно, что память буфера просто еще никем не затерта в этот момент, и вы просто передаете то, что продолжает лежать по указанному адресу. Но гарантии, что оно там будет лежать всегда при вызове вашей функции - нет.

Мне удалось удовлетворить вашу любознательность? :)